# Regexp для повторяющегося ровно 4 раза символа

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Например, `"JKKKKP".replace(Regexp, "s") // JsP`
Не знаю, имеет ли это значение, но язык - js. Нужен строго один и тот же любой символ, повторенный строго 4 раза.

Comment: Вам нужен это только для букв или для всех символов?

Comment: Регулярка вообще не должна находить последовательность из 5 и более символов? Или должна находить только 4?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
var str = "JKKKKP".replace(/(.)\1{3}/g, "s");
console.log(str);
```

Где

- `.` - любой символ
- `(.)` - группа из одного любого символа
- `\1` - ссылка на группу
- `{3}` - требуется повотрение ссылки три раза

Answer (score 3):

Используйте ссылки на подмаски

```
/(.)\1\1\1/
```

Answer (score 3):

Вот эта регулярка берет все повторяющийся символы (4 раза).

```
/(?=(.))\1{4,4}/g
```

```js
var str = "JKKKKP";
var reg = /(?=(.))\1{4,4}/g;
console.log(str.replace(reg, "s"));
```

А если вам нужно до 4 то можете сделать так `{1,4}`
Первый это минимальное количество совпадений, а второе значение максимальное.